# My code to edit is missing from visual studio 2017 C#!

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I know it's probably solved very easily but my actual code to edit on my console program is missing and I can't edit it. I can still run the code I just cannot view it. I am on a Mac

Comment: Can you share a screenshot? Can you open the project itself? Can you see the solution explorer?

Answer (score 0):

On the top right you have the "Quick launch" textbox. It's like mac spotlight. Type there "Solution explorer" or open it from menù "View--> Solution explorer" and a window with the code will appear. There you can open the code files.

[image: Quick launch]